# What is wrong with my Windows GTK+ for Python installation?

Tags: python, windows, installation, pygtk, gtk

Getting pretty frustrated with this. I installed pygtk 2.24, pycairo 1.8.10, and pyobject 2.28.3 all for my 32 bit system and my installed Python version of 2.7. I have GTK+ installed and working.

Also, I have the path to "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0" set in sys.path (where pygtk and pobject reside) and my Path system variable for GTK_BASEPATH is set to C:\gtk, where GTK+ resides.

I get this error when I attempt to import gtk:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    import gtk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gtk\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import gobject as _gobject
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gobject\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from glib import spawn_async, idle_add, timeout_add, timeout_add_seconds, \
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\glib\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from glib._glib import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**

Found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091281/import-gtk-glib-produces-importerror-dll-load-failed), and I found a variable for GtkSharp (don't know where it came from) but removing it did not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try uninstalling all of that (including GTK+, unless something else needs it) and use the [PyGTK all-in-one installer instead](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/).

Comment: This worked. I thought that was the one I had downloaded, but on a second glance it was not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling your own, make sure you go in the 'dist' folder and run the created installer to use your version on your machine.

Windows compilation directions: 
http://git.gnome.org/browse/pygtk/tree/README.win32